# Change application wide style in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, app.xaml

I have a Style for Buttons for my whole application that looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
some style code here
</Style>
```

It does affect every button that is used like that:

```
<Button />
```

But when I want to alter one specific button like this:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeBoolean}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

it get's the windows standard style.

Comment: which is normal, because you are overriding your global button style. what you can do is create an additionnal style which combine the two styles you are willing to apply, or put your global style in your local button style

Comment: can't I make a global style which I can alter with triggers like I do with the standard windows style? Making a new style for every button that needs a trigger seems wrong.

Comment: course you can. Give your first style a resource name, then use the same syntax as your first style by basing `basedOnn`your trigger needed style on the resource name of your first style by using `Style="{StaticResource trigger_style_name}"` on your control

Comment: i had that before, but then i have to assing this style to every button used in the whole application. I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: sorry, my guess is you would have to do so. you would have to create an "appButton" which would inherit windows button an apply your application style. Then in your whole application replace button control by your button_inherited_class_name in xaml files. that's why when starting a WPF application good practice is to inherit every control in custom control classes. I don't see another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `BasedOn` attribute:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeBoolean}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```